# Grails Redis Cache - Calling @Cacheable annoted method indirectly - how to work

Tags: caching, grails, redis

I have the following case in grails 2.5.3:

```
EmployeeService{

    @Cacheable(value = "employees")
    public List<Employee> getEmployeeList() {
        return Employee.list()
    }

    public Employee getEmployee(long id){
        return getEmployeeList().find{it.id == id}
    }
}



EmployeeController{

    def employeeService

    def getEmployee(long id){
        render employeeService.getEmployee(id) as JSON
    }
}
```

My problem is - the `@Cacheable` annotated method in `EmployeeService` does not store data in Redis cache, what should I do to accomplish exactly this case.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caching is provided by spring. So you need to use the spring way to call methods to apply the caching:

```
EmployeeService {
    def grailsApplication

    @Cacheable(value = "employees")
    public List<Employee> getEmployeeList() {
        return Employee.list()
    }

    public Employee getEmployee(long id){
        return proxy.getEmployeeList().find {it.id == id}
    }

    // using springs bean proxy ensures cacheable aspects are applied
    private getProxy() {
        grailsApplication.mainContext.employeeService
    }
}
```